# RTAB-Map rgbd_launch error Map received with code error 1! problem

Tags: slam, rgbd, jackal, rgbd-slam, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am trying to use RTAB-Map on my clearpath Jackal robot (am reading its topics through the same wifi). I am not using OpenNI because my robot and ASUS Xtion rgbd camera have already been set up to publish the camera topics (as shown  what i get after I type in rostopic list):

```
/camera/camera_nodelet_manager/bond
/camera/depth/camera_info
/camera/depth/image
/camera/depth/image_raw
/camera/depth/image_rect
/camera/depth/image_rect_raw
/camera/depth/points
/camera/depth_rectify_depth/parameter_descriptions
/camera/depth_rectify_depth/parameter_updates
/camera/depth_registered/camera_info
/camera/depth_registered/image_raw
/camera/depth_registered/image_raw/compressedDepth
/camera/depth_registered/points
/camera/depth_registered/sw_registered/camera_info
/camera/depth_registered/sw_registered/image_rect
/camera/depth_registered/sw_registered/image_rect_raw
/camera/driver/parameter_descriptions
/camera/driver/parameter_updates
/camera/ir/camera_info
/camera/ir/image
/camera/rectify_color/parameter_descriptions
/camera/rectify_color/parameter_updates
/camera/rgb/camera_info
/camera/rgb/image_raw
/camera/rgb/image_rect_color
/camera/rgb/image_rect_color/compressed
```

Whenever I run roslaunch rtabmap_ros rgbd_mapping.launch rtabmap_args:="--delete_db_on_start", it takes long for my RTAB to open up, and when it does run, I get the following on the Progress dialog of the RTAB GUI when I click on the Download all clouds button (looks like a refresh button) and I select any of the Options:

```
17:42:11 Downloading the map (global=false ,optimized=true)...
17:42:14 Downloading the map... done.
17:42:14 [ERROR] Map received with code error 1!
```

Meanwhile, the terminal keeps displaying:

```
[ WARN] [1464793454.065524286]: TF_OLD_DATA ignoring data from the past for frame camera_rgb_frame at time 1.46479e+09 according to authority unknown_publisher
```

Possible reasons are listed at http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Errors%20explained

Anyone know how I might be able to fix this? Thanks for the help! :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235828/rtab-map-rgbd_launch-error-map-received-with-code-error-1!-problem/) by [Gabe](https://answers.ros.org/users/27033/gabe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-06-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think I just answered the same question [here](http://official-rtab-map-forum.67519.x6.nabble.com/RTAB-Map-rgbd-launch-error-Map-received-with-code-error-1-tp1379p1384.html).

cheers

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2016-06-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0